# Using Google App Engine how do I open an html page?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Using Google App Engine I hope to learn some very basic knowledge with this question. I want to be able to open an index.html page that is placed in a folder when I open the application.

I generated a new application using 'Google App Engine Launcher'

I slightly modified the app.yaml and it now looks like the following...

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /templates
  static_dir: templates

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

I also have a added a directory called 'templates'.

In the directory I placed a file called 'index.html'.

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world cls
</body>
</html>
```

My main.py hasn't been modified so it looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Any ideas on what I need to do or change to find success?

Regards,

Chris

> > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > >                   My code has changed in a big way because of a comment from Gwyn
> > >
> > > I now have the standard Django template code from link (https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine)
> > >       Gwyn eventually the index.html file will be something a little more than a static page so a direct URL that you described won't work. You did teach me though and that will come in handy as I progress. I want to bring in some Polymer code once I get the basics figured out here...

So if anyone can help me feed up a hello world from within a 'templates' folder using an index.html page from a standard django codeset generated from the Google Developers Console then your answer would be very much appreciated here.

Regards,

Chris

Comment: If you're just trying to serve a static html page then you don't need python at all, if you navigate to /templates/index.html it should load. If you are trying to serve dynamic content however, you will need python, and preferably some kind of templating framework such as jinja2. Here's a working example https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates

Comment: @GwynHowell your comment led me to (https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine) and from there I downloaded django code so my original code is no longer valid. This still isn't exactly what I need but I think you got me closer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to update this so if anyone else is struggling they may find success also...
I want to thank both of Gwyn Howell and Kristian Damian. I used both of your comments to come up with an answer for anyone else that has the same question.

1. I went to clarify that I am using the downloaded Python SDK for Google App Engine
2. I made a sample python project using File|Create New Application - Python 2.7
3. I ran the project to make sure it was working without any of my changes
4. I then decided I would use 'Jinja2' for my template engine
5. I made a 'templates' folder and placed my 'about_v2.html' file in it
6. I modified the 'app.yaml' code to read

> ```
> application: helloworld
> version: 2
> runtime: python27
> api_version: 1
> threadsafe: yes
>
> handlers:
> - url: /favicon\.ico
>   static_files: favicon.ico
>   upload: favicon\.ico
>
> - url: .*
>   script: main.app
>
> libraries:
> - name: webapp2
>   version: latest
> - name: jinja2
>   version: latest
> ```

7. I modified the 'main.py' code to read

> ```
> import os
> import webapp2
> import jinja2
>
> env = jinja2.Environment(
>   loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
> ```
>
> 'templates')))
>
> ```
> class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
>     def get(self):
>         self.response.write('Hello world! <a href="/about_v2.html">About</a>.<br />')
>
> class AboutPage_v2(webapp2.RequestHandler):
>     def get(self):
>         template_values = {
>
>         }
>
>         template = env.get_template('about_v2.html')
>         self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
>
>
> app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
>     ('/', MainHandler),
>     ('/about_v2.html', AboutPage_v2)],
>
>                               debug=True)
> ```

8. I then ran the project on my local machine and was able to get to the url

I hope this answer helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

First, to use HTML, do you need a template engine, in app engine you can use this [EZT, Cheetah, ClearSilver, Quixote, Django, and Jinja2](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates?hl=en)  but for simplicity, you can modify your code to send the html directly

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('<html><header><title>This is title</title></header><body>Hello world cls</body></html>')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

But as  Gwyn Howell says, for more complicated stuff you must use a template engine

Comment: Your answer isn't exactly what I needed but when you and Gwyn both mentioned Template engines I think I saw a glimpse of hope.